# Xstream - adding an attribute to the root node

Tags: xstream

I am using Xstream to serialize a list of objects. ( a list of Task objects ).

I am returning the XML to a jsp page.

```
HashMap<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("Task", Task.class);
xstream.alias("Tasks", Vector.class);
m.put("task", task);
m.put("xml", xstream.toXML(l));

return new ModelAndView("task", m);
```

The final XML structure looks like this:

```
<Tasks>
 <Task>
    <TaskId>1<TaskId>
    <TaskName>Task 1</TaskName>
    etc...
 </Task>
```

The root node of  comes back as a Vector, I am using xtream to alias that to "Tasks" as shown above.

When I create a new task, or update a task, I have code that rearranges the order of the tasks, numbering etc. so I am returning the complete list of Task objects.  But I would like to store the value of the single TaskId that I just created/updated as an attribute in the root node of the XML structure so I don't have to make 2 calls across the network and my client code can have access to the id of the new/updated Task row in the db.

So for example if I created a new Task and it is assigned a TaskId of 5, I would want to store the task id in the root node like this:

```
<Tasks myId="5">
<Task>
    <TaskId>1</TaskId>
    <TaskName>Task 1</TaskName>
</Task>
<Task>
    <TaskId>2</TaskId>
    <TaskName>Task 2</TaskName>
</Task>
...
<Task>
    <TaskId>5</TaskId>
    <TaskName>Task 5</TaskName>
</Task>
etc
```

How do I accomplish this with Xstream?  Do I need to use an XSLT file to transform the XML output?  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by writing a converter for tasks and set attribute field as follows in the marshal method,

> writer.addAttribute("mydtl",tasks.get(2).getTaskName());

Refer to following link for creating converters,

http://x-stream.github.io/converter-tutorial.html